# My app crashes for tablet users?

Tags: android, crash, tablet

I have a published application on Google Play and I keep getting crash reports for devices for 7" and over. My game utilizes a device's accelerometer so I put code to check for an accelerometer and proceed the game only if one is found. The thing is the devices that crash have accelerometers. I have analyzed my code thoroughly and I can't see why the game doesn't run on tablets so I thought I'd get other's perspective. The crash is always a nullPointerException in onCreate of my mainActivity but the error reports don't specify where.

Here is my MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    android.graphics.PointF mBallPos, mBallSpd;
    int mScrWidth, mScrHeight;
    Handler RedrawHandler = new Handler(); //so redraw occurs in main thread
    Timer mTmr = null;
    TimerTask mTsk = null;
    BallView mBallView = null;


    int n = 1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button playGameButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playGameButton);
        final Button turnOffAdsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.turnOffAdsButton);
        final Button shareButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
        final Button rateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rateButton);

        final TextView musicTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.musicTextView);
        final TextView instructionsTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.instructionsTextView);
        final TextView titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        n = intent.getIntExtra("adsNumber", 0);

        final RelativeLayout mainView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.game_title);

        //get screen dimensions
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        mScrWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
        mScrHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
        mBallPos = new PointF();
        mBallSpd = new PointF();

        //create variables for ball position and speed
        mBallPos.x = mScrWidth / 2;
        mBallPos.y = mScrHeight / 2;
        mBallSpd.x = 0;
        mBallSpd.y = 0;

        //create initial ball

        mBallView = new BallView(this, mBallPos.x, mBallPos.y, mScrWidth/30);
        mBallView.setColor(0xFFFFFFFF);

        mainView.addView(mBallView); //add ball to main screen
        mBallView.invalidate(); //call onDraw in BallView


            //listener for accelerometer, use anonymous class for simplicity
            ((SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE)).registerListener(
                    new SensorEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
                            //set ball speed based on phone tilt (ignore Z axis)
                            mBallSpd.x = -event.values[0] * 6;
                            mBallSpd.y = event.values[1] * 6;
                            //timer event will redraw ball
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
                        } //ignore
                    },
                    ((SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE))
                            .getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER).get(0),
                    SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

        //Check if device has an accelerometer
        SensorManager sensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        Sensor accelerometerSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        if (accelerometerSensor != null)
        {
            runCircle(); //Begins sampling
        }
        else {
            showAccelerometerFragment();
        }

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.chopin);
        mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

        mediaPlayer.start();

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                YoYo.with(Techniques.Wobble)
                        .duration(3000)
                        .playOn(titleTextView);
            }
        });

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                YoYo.with(Techniques.BounceIn)
                        .duration(2000)
                        .playOn(playGameButton);
            }
        });

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                YoYo.with(Techniques.BounceIn)
                        .duration(2000)
                        .playOn(shareButton);
            }
        });

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                YoYo.with(Techniques.BounceIn)
                        .duration(2000)
                        .playOn(turnOffAdsButton);
            }
        });

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                YoYo.with(Techniques.BounceIn)
                        .duration(2000)
                        .playOn(rateButton);
            }
        });

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                YoYo.with(Techniques.RotateInUpLeft)
                        .duration(1000)
                        .playOn(musicTextView);
            }
        });

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                YoYo.with(Techniques.RotateInDownRight)
                        .duration(1000)
                        .playOn(instructionsTextView);
            }
        });





        playGameButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            goToGameScreen();

            }
        });

        musicTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                {
                    //stop or pause your media player mediaPlayer.stop(); or mediaPlayer.pause();
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    musicTextView.setText("Turn Music On");

                } else
                {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    musicTextView.setText("Turn Music Off");

                }
            }
        });

        shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, getResources().getString(R.string.sharing_string) + "\n\n https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=benyamephrem.tilt&hl=en");
                sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                startActivity(sendIntent);
            }
        });

        instructionsTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showInstructionFragment();
            }
        });

        rateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rateGameRedirect();
            }
        });

        turnOffAdsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                turnOffAdsRedirect();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() //app moved to background, stop background threads
    {   super.onPause();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }

    private void turnOffAdsRedirect() {
        try {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=benyamephrem.tilt&hl=en")));
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=benyamephrem.tilt&hl=en")));
        }
    }

    private void rateGameRedirect() {
        try {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=benyamephrem.tilt&hl=en")));
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe){
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=benyamephrem.tilt&hl=en")));
        }

    }


    public void goToGameScreen(){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GameScreen.class);
        intent.putExtra("adsNumber", n);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    private void showInstructionFragment() {
        InstructionsFragment dialog = new InstructionsFragment();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "instruction_dialog");
    }

    private void showAccelerometerFragment() {
        AccelerometerFragment dialog = new AccelerometerFragment();
        dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "instruction_dialog");
    }

    private void runCircle() {

        //create timer to move ball to new position
        mTmr = new Timer();
        mTsk = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {

                //move ball based on current speed
                mBallPos.x += mBallSpd.y;
                mBallPos.y += -mBallSpd.x;

                //if ball goes off screen, reposition to opposite side of screen
                    if (mBallPos.x > mScrWidth) mBallPos.x = 0;
                    if (mBallPos.y > mScrHeight) mBallPos.y = 0;
                    if (mBallPos.x < 0) mBallPos.x = mScrWidth;
                    if (mBallPos.y < 0) mBallPos.y = mScrHeight;


                //update ball class instance
                mBallView.x = mBallPos.x;
                mBallView.y = mBallPos.y;

                //redraw ball. Must run in background thread to prevent thread lock.
                RedrawHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mBallView.invalidate();
                    }
                });


            } //run
        }; // TimerTask

        mTmr.schedule(mTsk, 0, 10); //start timer (Timer)
    }


}
```

And here is my Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"  />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity
        android:name=".UI.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UI.GameScreen"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_game_screen"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:parentActivityName=".UI.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="benyamephrem.tilt.UI.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".UI.Redirect"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_redirect"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:parentActivityName=".UI.GameScreen" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="benyamephrem.tilt.UI.GameScreen" />
    </activity>

</application>
```

This is the error I get in the developer console:

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity : java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1973)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1999)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4513)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:974)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:741)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: jav

a.lang.NullPointerException
at benyamephrem.tilt.UI.MainActivity.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
... 11 more
```

Comment: add log here to check issue.

Comment: @AndoMasahashi I put in the error I get in the console, I don't have a real tablet to test on.